# How to send and receive messages from socket in Haskell

Tags: sockets, haskell, tcp

I am trying to create a `TCP` server in Haskell and so far i am not able to open a connection from a google browser extension and keep it open:

**Error**

`Server.exe: Network.Socket.sendBuf: failed (Unknown error)`

**Code**

```
import Network.Socket
import qualified Network.Socket.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString.Char8(pack,unpack)

main::IO()
main=do
    sock<-socket AF_INET Stream 0
    bind sock (SockAddrInet 8500 iNADDR_ANY)
    listen sock 3
    (csock,_)<-accept sock
    loop csock

loop::Socket->IO()
loop csock=do
    print "Begining of loop"
   -- dat<-B.recv csock 2000
    sent<-B.send  csock $ pack "Hi!!"
  --  print $ unwords  ["Received :",unpack dat]
    print "End of loop"
    loop csock
```

I have tried first only with sending messages and i get the up error, if i uncomment the lines with `recv` it hangs

**Output with commented lines**

```
"Begining of loop"
"End of loop"
"Begining of loop"
"End of loop"
"Begining of loop"
"End of loop"
"Begining of loop"
Server.exe: Network.Socket.sendBuf: failed (Unknown error)
```

**Output with uncommented lines**

```
"Begining of loop"
"Received : GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8500\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nOrigin: chrome-extension://pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.9,ro;q=0.8\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: WY87jPXNRfk/WM5T20O8Jg==\r\nSec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n\r\n"
"End of loop"
"Begining of loop"
```

**P.S**
I am using `Simple WebSocket Client`-extension on Chrome and in both cases the connection appears "Opening" and not "Opened" even though the program runs a couple of iterations as you can see in the output(s)

Comment: I think you want to use the `forever` function. It is documented in Control.Monad as common approach to network sockets inputs. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html

Comment: So you're trying to connect to the server with the Chrome web browser(?) It looks to me like Chrome sends a HTTP request, your program replies with `Hi!!` (not a valid HTTP response), Chrome closes the network connection, your program crashes trying to write to a closed socket. See what happens if you send a valid HTTP reply...

Comment: Now i realised that the chrome extension actually tries to open a `websocket` while my haskell program binds a raw `socket`.

Comment: @lsmor He's doing the recursive call properly, which amounts to the same thing as using `forever` and should work just fine. But yes, `forever` would probably be more idiomatic.

Comment: Yeah, websockets are different from raw TCP sockets. It looks like websockets use an HTTP header section for the initial handshake, but later allow full-duplex communication a bit like raw TCP. [reference](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server worked just fine.The problem was that i was trying to connect using `Chrome Simple WebSocket Client` extension , which as the name says , tries to open a `WebSocket` connection , while my server handles simple `Socket` ones.

I tried connecting to the server using `telnet` and it worked just fine (both sending and receiveing).